# import rrule plugin with fullcalendar v4 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, fullcalendar, es6-modules

I'm having problems with getting fullcalendar version 4 to show recurring events in a React app.

[I used this tutorial](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/rrule-plugin)

the statement `import 'fullcalendar/plugins/rrule';` gives me the error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fullcalendar/plugins/rrule'
```

So I changed the import statement to `'fullcalendar/dist/plugins/rrule';`
Now I get errors from rollup which I solved by adding `external: [ 'rrule' ]`in `rollup.config.js`

All I want to do is show some recurring events in `fullcalendar` version 4 (so no JQuery dependency) and React.

Any help would be appreciated

I started a project on code sandbox but couldn't get fullcalendar v4 to load.

[image: Edit n0lvqzmw9m]

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but for someone whom searching it in future.
The proper way for importing rrule in react first you need to

yarn add @fullcalendar/rrule or npm install -s @fullcalendar/rrule

Then in reactjs component:

import rrulePlugin from '@fullcalendar/rrule';

And finally add it to full calenadar component in the plugins property

plugins={[rrulePlugin, ...other plugins]}

Documentation can be found here

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this question is a little old, but i've had faced similar problem and this is how i solved it.

First, in your CodeSandbox you're import without the @

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
```

Second in your dependencies you haven't installed rrule, just the plugin, you can install by running:

```
yarn add rrule
```

or

```
npm install rrule
```

you can find full documentation here: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx, I'll try that out